# How can I change the default editor options for PyroCMS?

Tags: wysiwyg, pyrocms

I'm not sure if `TinyMCE` is being used or not, but is it possible to add additional options to the text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is `CKEditor` and yes you can change the default configuration. Just go to admin panel and go to `settings`, there is an editor tab witch lets you edit the configuration.